# Connection to Spark SQL JDBC through Java Application fails

Tags: java, apache-spark, jdbc, hive, apache-spark-sql

I have written a Java Application to perform SQL Queries on a hive-based database, using Spark SQL. However, connecting to the Spark SQL through JDBC from my Java Application gives me a **connection refused** error. The piece of code that I have written is below:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    Class.forName("org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver");
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hive2://<ip>:10015/default","","");
    System.out.println("Connected!");
}
```

I am using `HDP 2.5` on a `Centos 7 OS` inside a `VMWare` workstation on `Windows 7`. The code is being run from Eclipse Neon, `JDK 8`.

I am able to connect to `port 10000` (for Hive) on the same IP from the code. Also, I have tried to make JDBC connections from Beeline to both `10000` and `10015` and both of them work properly. Beeline syntax is:

```
!connect jdbc:hive2://127.0.0.1:10015
```

The stack trace from the Java Code is:

```
1300 [main] INFO  org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection  - Could not open client transport with JDBC Uri: jdbc:hive2://192.168.225.128:10015/default
java.sql.SQLException: Could not open client transport with JDBC Uri: jdbc:hive2://192.168.225.128:10015/default: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection.openTransport(HiveConnection.java:215)
at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection.<init>(HiveConnection.java:163)
at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver.connect(HiveDriver.java:105)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
```

Comment: The error suggests that it is not listening on port 10015, or at least not on IP address 192.168.225.128

Comment: Used 'netstat' to verify that the port is listening. Also, if the beeline is able to connect to the service on 10015, the port must be working,

Comment: No, because there you are connecting to 127.0.0.1. Ports can be open on specific IP addresses and closed on others on the same host.

Comment: Should I do something about it from the firewall ? What do you think might be the issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to work it out, and the solution is fairly simple. You need to start Spark Thrift Servers to make this work.

### Starting Spark Thrift Server using Ambari Web UI:

Just go to Ambari -> Spark. On the top-right corner, you can see options. Click on it and start Spark Thrift Servers from there.

In case you do not see Spark Thrift Servers in the Web UI, go to SPARK_HOME/sbin and type:

```
./start-thriftserver.sh --hiveconf hive.server2.thrift.port=10015
```

Wait for a minute or two after the server has started and you can make the JDBC connections successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Have you stored the hive metadata in the mysql? Maybe the mysql server binds to localhost. Try to view `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf`, and find this row:

```
bind-address = 127.0.0.1
```

remove it, and restart the mysql server.

Comment: I did not find the file mentioned above. Also, the hive metadata is stored in HIve metastore. Any other suggestions ?

Comment: I know hive metdata is stored in hive metastore , which Relational database you choose to store it , is derby ?

Comment: No, it's MySQL 5.6. I couldn't find that file you mentioned. I used 'find' to see if any such file existed at all, no results. Please let me know if there is some other name, or a solution.

Comment: May be you can find the document /etc/mysql/my.cnf